# How to decouple MDB and classes sending soap requests

Tags: java, message-driven-bean

We connect to external partners webservices via a MDB on Websphere. One MDB contain code for 15 partners. When the MDB receive a message it finds out which partner it is for and calls the partnerHandler class. The class communicate with the exernal partner and sends the reply back to the MDB that returns the reply to JMS.

The problem with this setup is that if there is a change in one partner class or a new should be added then we reploy the whole MDB with all partner classes.

Can you please suggest a better setup where we do not need to redeploy all classes and we do not need to make a MDB for each partner.
Thanks :O)